# Donations to Influence Voting

Tags: voting

[18 U.S. Code § 597.Expenditures to influence voting](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/597) basically states how it is illegal for someone to pay someone or receive payment to vote a certain manner. However, would it be illegal for someone to vote a certain way in exchange for a donation to a charitable organization or nonprofit?

Comment: Is a "donation to a charitable organization or nonprofit" not a form of payment?

Comment: it is not made out to the voter and so seems to be allowed under the given wording

Comment: Which party is the individual being compelled to vote for?